# WeakReference symbol cannot be found

Tags: java

Already import the weakreference but the compiler cannot find the symbol, what wrong? There a memory leak in DumpReceiver.java I thought weakreference might free after used?

```
import java.lang.ref.WeakReference;

Receiver r = new DumpReceiver(System.out);
WeakReference<Receiver> wr = new WeakReference<DumpReceiver>(r);


MidiInDump.java:64: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor WeakReference(javax.sound.midi.Receiver)
location: class java.lang.ref.WeakReference<DumpReceiver>
                WeakReference<Receiver> wr = new WeakReference<DumpReceiver>(r);

                                             ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look closely at the error message. It's not talking about the class (it's finding that just fine). It is talking about the constructor. It doesn't find a constructor that takes a `javax.sound.midi.Receiver` argument on the type `WeakReference<DumpReceiver>`. Looking at the JavaDoc of `WeakReference<T>` there is one constructor that takes an argument of type `T`.

You're trying to create a `WeakReference<DumpReceiver>` but try to pass in an object of type `javax.sound.midi.Receiver`. You either need to create a `WeakReference<Receiver>` instead or change the variable `r` to be of type `DumpReceiver`.

Comment: I agree (+1). This is the kind of thing that an IDE tells you.

Comment: Yeah, being actionscript developer, I still has lot to learn but found it is not this problem that caused memory leak. I wonder who can spent time to read my MIDI code?

Comment: I meant I have found one function that keep increasing memory after dump MIDI code to the console, if you like to look at it?

Comment: @user217582: if you have a new question start a new topic.